# Nvidia drivers not identified after reinstalling

Tags: 14.04, nvidia, cuda

So there was some glitch in CUDA8 on the server, nvidia drivers couldn't be identified. I purged nvidia, then kernel was downgraded to 116, then upgraded back to 119. I reinstalled driver (nvidia 384), and installed cuda drivers (`sudo apt-get -y install cuda-drivers`), but I keep getting these errors:

```
nvidia-smi
NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver. Make sure that the latest NVIDIA driver is installed and running.
```

lsmod and does not identify nvidia, but

```
ubuntu-drivers devices | grep nv
driver   : nvidia-384 - third-party free
driver   : nvidia-390 - third-party free recommended
```

and

```
modinfo nvidia-384
filename:       /lib/modules/4.4.0-119-generic/updates/dkms/nvidia_384.ko
alias:          char-major-195-*
version:        384.130
supported:      external
license:        NVIDIA
srcversion:     586B4E0CF4083A6BC41A33B
alias:          pci:v000010DEd00000E00sv*sd*bc04sc80i00*
alias:          pci:v000010DEd*sv*sd*bc03sc02i00*
alias:          pci:v000010DEd*sv*sd*bc03sc00i00*
depends:        
vermagic:       4.4.0-119-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
parm:           NVreg_Mobile:int
parm:           NVreg_ResmanDebugLevel:int
parm:           NVreg_RmLogonRC:int
parm:           NVreg_ModifyDeviceFiles:int
parm:           NVreg_DeviceFileUID:int
parm:           NVreg_DeviceFileGID:int
parm:           NVreg_DeviceFileMode:int
parm:           NVreg_UpdateMemoryTypes:int
parm:           NVreg_InitializeSystemMemoryAllocations:int
parm:           NVreg_UsePageAttributeTable:int
parm:           NVreg_MapRegistersEarly:int
parm:           NVreg_RegisterForACPIEvents:int
parm:           NVreg_CheckPCIConfigSpace:int
parm:           NVreg_EnablePCIeGen3:int
parm:           NVreg_EnableMSI:int
parm:           NVreg_TCEBypassMode:int
parm:           NVreg_UseThreadedInterrupts:int
parm:           NVreg_EnableStreamMemOPs:int
parm:           NVreg_MemoryPoolSize:int
parm:           NVreg_RegistryDwords:charp
parm:           NVreg_RegistryDwordsPerDevice:charp
parm:           NVreg_RmMsg:charp
parm:           NVreg_AssignGpus:charp
```

But

```
    sudo modprobe nvidia_384
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'nvidia_384': Exec format error
```

I'm not sure what to make of it all. Why isn't the GPU (Tesla K40) identified?  Should I reinstall CUDA?

EDIT: lspci actually identifies it:

```
lspci | grep -i nvidia
03:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GF119 [NVS 315] (rev a1)
03:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation GF119 HDMI Audio Controller (rev a1)
04:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK110BGL [Tesla K40m] (rev a1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the Nvidia drivers supplied by Ubuntu.  Enable the "Universe" software source, and under the "Additional Drivers" tab, select the Nvidia 384, tested driver. It will be 384.111, and the ubuntu-drivers output will look like:

```
driver   : nvidia-384 - distro non-free recommended
```

After nvidia-smi sees the driver, then try the cuda install.